# mysql complex statement

Tags: mysql

Problem: Two tables, first one contains userid(constraint fk) and column 'name', second table contains two columns of int and id(foreign key), what I need, is to find max(column1-column2) and assign it with name from first table;

what I was doing: 
mysql>

```
select u.name, MAX(table2.column1-table2.column2) As var 
  from table1 u, table2 b 
 where u.userID(from table1) = b.userID(from table2)
   and (b.column1-b.column2) = var;
```

in this case it says "unknown column var", is it possible withoud triggers/procedures?

[image]

any1?:)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `var` in your WHERE clause with `MAX(table2.column1-table2.column2)`?

Comment: thats your requirement?you try to find the max value per name? there is no group by in your statement?

Comment: I added image to clarify :) I know its not complex for some1 but it is for me right now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try a subquery instead?

```
select u.name, (b.column1 - b.column2) as var 
  from table1 u, table2 b 
 where u.userID(from table1) = b.userID(from table2)
   and (b.column1-b.column2) = ( select MAX(column1 - column2) from table2);
```

Comment: THAAANK YOU :))) this one was the solution. appreciate

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the correct solution:

```
select u.name, 
    MAX(table2.column1-table2.column2) As var 
from table1 u
    join table2 b 
        on b.userId = u.userId
where u.userID(from table1) = b.userID(from table2)
group by u.name
```

Comment: alright, it didnt take me where I wanted 2 anyways thank you for responses, I`ll just load it in ResultSet and manage it programm-side;] thanks 4 responses.

Comment: now i understand (i did not see the image before), is marvos solution not right for you?